# Regular Expression to Replace Escaped Hebrew Characters

Tags: regex

I have a string with escaped hebrew characters, so for example my string contains these hex values:

%d7%90%d7%94%d7%95%d7%93%d7%a8%d7%9d

which represent:

אהודרם

Is there a regular expression I can apply to this string, to return its actual Hebrew characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = URLDecoder.decode("%d7%90%d7%94%d7%95%d7%93%d7%a8%d7%9d", "UTF-8");
```

Regex is without function call backs unfeasible: every %xx would need to become a byte in a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence.